# Getting 404 Error In Admin from Extensions

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, configuration, admin-panel, system-config

I am using Magento v1.8. I am trying to install extensions by using Magento Connect Manager. Everything works fine till the installation of the extension. But the Moment I click on the Extension via System > Configuration > Extension it gives me a 404 Error Page. Evertime. It's happening with every extension. Please let me know what should I do...?

Comment: Could you add to your question what extension this is about?

Comment: please check this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13924/how-to-avoid-404-error-on-new-extension-installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is standard Magento behaviour. Log out and log back in so that the acl can reload.