# Abandoned Cart in Magento 1.9.2.4 showing error Access Denied in backend

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I installed the extension. But it shows Access Denied in backend

Comment: Just out of curiosity what extension are you talking about ? Also try logout and log back in.

Comment: I did it  two or more time. Clear cache. But error still remains same

Comment: Where did you get the module ?

Comment: Amasty Abandoned Cart  extension, I had installed.

Comment: I puurchased it.

Comment: Please contact Amasty support directly as we can't help you regarding 3rd party modules.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Muhammad Ahsan Horani above, whenever a module is installed it is required to log out and then log back in.

This is because upon login Magento caches and stores to the admin session the ACL available to view certain areas of the site. New installations do not have their configuration of system configuration and routes loaded into ACL so they are not available unless you log back in.

See this answer from @marius for more technical information:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/13930/336

Answer (score 0):

- Clear var/cache
- Logout from admin and then login again
- Extension will work

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/62247)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism but part of this is actually the correct answer

Comment: See this http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/13930/336

Comment: @philwinkle damn mate you're after me today ^^ I flagged it as not an answer because to me that should be a comment "did you try...?" as it's basically the usual suspects for almost every extension problem. I just feel like if this is an answer without knowing more details about the error it can be an answer for a lot of questions. My bad if it's actually the right answer I sometimes want to get too much into details before helping.

Comment: I'm trying to be sensitive to the answer style of non-native speakers; technically his answer is the right answer. Should a technically correct answer have long and flowery prose? Maybe let's chat in Slack.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism Please mark this as correct and accepted if you found it right.

Comment: @philwinkle Thanks for praising. At least I deserve an Up vote.